# I wanna find a button using LINQ and put it on a variable and cast it to Button and show it in form put i get an error,what should i do

Tags: c#, .net, linq, button, windows-forms-designer

```
        Dictionary<string, string> dic_index = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        dic_index.Add("reset path", "btn_resetPath");
        dic_index.Add("open folder", "btn_openFolder");
        dic_index.Add("about", "btn_About");
        dic_index.Add("close", "btn_close");

        foreach(var item in dic_index)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text.Contains(item.Key))
            {
                Button btn = (Button)from i in Controls.OfType<Button>() where i.Name == item.Value select i; // the line of error is here
                btn.Show();

            }
        }
```

I wanna find a button using LINQ and put it on a variable and cast it to Button and show it in form put i get an error that it say: Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'WhereEnumerableIterator`1[System.Windows.Forms.Button]' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement `from i in Controls.OfType<Button>() where i.Name == item.Value select i` returns an `IEnumerable<Button>`, not a `Button`.
You have to call something like `(xxx).Single()` on it, then you will get your button and you will not need to unbox additionally.

Comment: can you give me the code example?

Comment: @Mahdinoroozi `Button btn = (from i in Controls.OfType<Button>() where i.Name == item.Value select i).SingleOrDefault();`.

Comment: @AlexanderPowolozki your answer was the base of what i wanted to do thankss:)

Comment: @Mahdinoroozi almost all answers are based on your code, if you want to get help here, you should upvote and mark any answer that answers your question.